# Create a line chart with individual lines for each day of the week?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, charts

I have the following data in a database table,
**Columns**: Date, Hour(from 1 to 24) and Temperature.

I want to create a line chart that will show in the x-axis the hours from 1 to 24 and in the Y-axis the Temperatures.

Now the tricky part is that I want to have different color lines for each date. So if the date is 2012-01-15 then I have a red line from 1 to 24 showing the variations in temperature. if the date is 2012-01-14 then a blue one also from 1 to 24.

To be clear I want to have multiple dates in one chart.

Here is some of code I have

```
        SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString");
        conn2.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd2.Connection = conn2;
        cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM observation WHERE day BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate ORDER BY day ASC, hour ASC ";
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("fromDate", dateTimePicker2.Value.Date);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("toDate", dateTimePicker3.Value.Date);



        SqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("dateRange");
        dt.Columns.Add("day");
        dt.Columns.Add("hour");
        dt.Columns.Add("temp");

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        int counter = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader[1].ToString() != dt.TableName)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count != 0 && dt.TableName != "dateRange")
                {
                    dt.AcceptChanges();
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                    counter++;
                }
                dt = new DataTable(reader[1].ToString());
                dt.Columns.Add("day"):                    
                dt.Columns.Add("hour");
                dt.Columns.Add("temp");

            }
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = reader[2];
            dr[1] = reader[3];
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Visible = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series[i].Name = i.ToString();
            chart1.Series[i].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series[i].BorderWidth = 5;
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                chart1.Series[i].Color = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                chart1.Series[i].Color = Color.Green;
            }

            chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables[i];
            chart1.Series[i].XValueMember = "hour";
            chart1.Series[i].YValueMembers = "temp";
        }

        chart1.Legends[0].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        chart1.Legends[0].Docking = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Top;

        chart1.DataBind();
        chart1.Visible = true;

        cmd2.Connection.Close();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the part you are having trouble with?
Extracting the data from the database; creating the chart; working out the different colours to use for different dates; showing multiple lines in a single chart?
If you could post some code you've started with you could expect short and concise answers. Or are you looking for rough guidelines?

Comment: @Jonno What I'm having trouble at the moment is to show multiple lines while mantaining the 1 through 24 in the x-axis. I have tried to create multiple tables inside one DataSet but the is no way to indicate which table to use.... I'm not sure how to create multiple lines, would that be multiple series?

Comment: @Jonno. I added the code I have. I know it is messy :S Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I found was to re format my dataSource. I created a DataTable with the first column being Hours and it goes from 1 to 24. the following columns are one for each day that I want to represent.

There are two Queries. the first one is to know how many days are in the interval and to create the appropriate number of Columns and Series. The second Query is the one that brings in all the Data.

Here is the Code:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT day FROM observation WHERE day BETWEEN @from AND @to GROUP BY day";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("from", Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("to", Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo));
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("DATA");
        dt.Columns.Add("Hour");

        int days = 0;
        chart1.DataSource = dt;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(((DateTime)rdr[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

            if (days == 0)
            {
                chart1.Series[days].Name = ((DateTime)rdr[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
            else
            {
                chart1.Series.Add(((DateTime)rdr[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            }
            chart1.Series[((DateTime)rdr[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")].XValueMember = "Hour";
            chart1.Series[((DateTime)rdr[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")].YValueMembers = ((DateTime)rdr[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            chart1.Series[((DateTime)rdr[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            days++;
        }
        rdr.Close();

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Hour"] = i;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM observation WHERE day BETWEEN @from2 AND @to2 ORDER BY day ASC, hour ASC ";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("from2", Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("to2", Convert.ToDateTime(toDate));

        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            dt.Rows[((int)(rdr[2]) - 1)][(((DateTime)rdr[1]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))] = rdr[3];   
        }

        cmd.Connection.Close();
        rdr.Close();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        chart1.DataBind();
        chart1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to create multiple lines you do have to create mulitple series but i am not sure what type of chart you are using here is a very good tutorial about charts

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx

`Chart1.Series[0].Points.FindMinByValue().Color = Color.Red;` 
that should change the color you want to for every point.

Comment: If I create many series, how should I structure the DataSource to feed that many series?

Comment: I do not think you have to use many series if you use the example above and based on what you want to do, I would not bind the source i would manage every number with for-each loop this way I can manage the appearance and create many series.

Comment: I created a solution based on some of your info. you can see it below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

dtTest.Columns.Add("TimePoint", GetType(Integer))
dtTest.Columns.Add("Speed", GetType(Integer))

dtTest.Rows.Add(0, 0)
dtTest.Rows.Add(1000, 50)
dtTest.Rows.Add(2000, 50)
dtTest.Rows.Add(3000, 0)

With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)
  .AxisX.Minimum = 0
  .AxisX.Maximum = 3000
  .AxisY.Minimum = 0
  .AxisY.Maximum = 60
  .AxisY.Interval = 10
  .AxisX.Title = "Elapsed Time (ms)"
  .AxisY.Title = "Speed (km/hr)"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    With Chart1.Series(0)
      .Points.DataBind(dtTest.DefaultView, "TimePoint", "Speed", Nothing)
      .ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
      .BorderWidth = 4
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..